# Get active subscriptions count for a defined product and user in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm able to know whether a user has an active subscription for a given product:

```
$subscribed = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::user_has_subscription($userId, $productId, $status);
```

But I'm not managing to figure out how many subscriptions to this product that user has… *(Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin now supports a user buying multiple subscriptions)*.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This custom function will give you **the count of active subscriptions** in a very light SQL query, for a defined used ID and a specific subscription product ID:

```
function get_user_active_subscriptions_count( $product_id, $user_id = null ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // if the user_id is not set in function argument we get the current user ID
    if( null == $user_id )
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // return the active subscriptions for a define user and a defined product ID
    return $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p2 ON p.post_parent = p2.ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p2.ID = pm.post_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON pm.post_id = woi.order_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_subscription' AND p.post_status LIKE 'wc-active'
        AND p2.post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user' AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'
        AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'
    ");
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Usage for a defined product ID `9` and:**

1. A user ID as a dynamic variable `$user_id` :

   echo '

   Subscription count: ' . get_user_active_subscriptions_count( '9', $user_id ) . '

   ';
2. A defined user ID *(Here user ID is **`15`**)*:

   echo '

   Subscription count: ' . get_user_active_subscriptions_count( '9', '15' ) . '

   ';
3. The current user ID:

   echo '

   Subscription count: ' . get_user_active_subscriptions_count( '9' ) . '

   ';

The product ID can also be dynamic using a variable instead of an integer (for the product ID)

---

Update: To get **the total count of a product subscription** in active subscriptions for a defined used ID (in a very light SQL query):

```
function get_user_active_product_subscriptions_count( $product_id, $user_id = null ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // if the user_id is not set in function argument we get the current user ID
    if( null == $user_id )
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // return the active subscriptions for a define user and a defined product ID
    return $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT sum(woim2.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p2 ON p.post_parent = p2.ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p2.ID = pm.post_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON pm.post_id = woi.order_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim2 ON woim.order_item_id = woim2.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_subscription' AND p.post_status LIKE 'wc-active'
        AND p2.post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user' AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'
        AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id' AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'
        AND woim2.meta_key = '_qty'
    ");
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**The usage** is the same than above, but the result will be different as you will get the sum of the defined product subscription in active subscriptions (for a defined user ID (So it will sum the quantities of all items corresponding to the defined product ID in the subscriptions made by a user ID)…

Comment: Thanks for answering. But if I'm reading this correctly, it returns the count of all the user's active subscriptions? I'm really looking to know how many subscriptions a user has for a particular product (I have the product_id and the user_id).

Comment: Right. But again, I'd like to get the count of active subscriptions for a defined user id **and** a defined product id. ("... for a given product")

Comment: @ariel I have updated my answer… The code as I use is a simple unique light and fast query… try it please. thanks.

Comment: Hmm. It's not giving me the same answer as my suggestion. I've set up a user with several subscriptions made up of several products. Altogether, the user has ordered the same subscription-product 10 times in 3 separate subscriptions. My answer is giving 10, which is correct. With yours, I'm getting 3. Now, 3 is indeed the number of subscriptions this user has that include the given product. But in some of those subscriptions he has subscribed multiple times to the product.

Comment: @Ariel Sorry nut your question is really not clear… You where asking the number of **active subscriptions** a user has (for a given product) or not? **But not the number of subscriptions products with the same ID** for this user. So this answer is correct regarding your question.

Comment: Right, the question as expressed is ambiguous. The problem is that the word "subscriptions" has both a technical meaning in the context of Woocommerce Subscriptions, and a plain meaning in spoken English. I think both our answers are correct. Yours answers the question "How many Woocommerce subscriptions does a user have that include a subscription-product with a given ID". Mine answers the question, "How many times has a user subscribed (in the plain-English sense) to a product with a given ID". In any case, many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ariel I have updated my answer adding a new function that sums the quantities of all items corresponding to the defined product ID in the subscriptions maid by a specific user ID. The important thing is that you get something useful regarding your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I think that this works. I have no idea how efficient it is, but the answer seems to be right – given a particular user and particular product, this will return the quantity of subscriptions the user has for this product.
*(Make sure to provide the Wordpress user_id in the $user_id variable, and the Woocommerce product id in the $product_id variable.)*

```
$allSubscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscriptions($user_id);
$item_quantity = 0;
foreach ($allSubscriptions as $subscription){
    if (($subscription['status'] == 'active' || $subscription['status'] == 'pending-cancel') == false) continue;
    $order = wc_get_order($subscription['order_id']);
    // Iterating through each line-item in the order
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {
        if ($item_data->get_product()->get_id() != $product_id) continue;
        $item_quantity += $item_data->get_quantity();
    }
}
echo 'Quantity: ' . $item_quantity . '<br>';
```

Comment: WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscriptions is deprecated since 2.0
please use wcs_get_users_subscriptions